# Create first nonexistent file in a numbered sequence

Tags: linux, bash

i want to check if 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt and 4.txt are on this folder

if 1.txt exist  it need to check 2.txt

if 2.txt exist it will check if 3.txt exist   and

if 3.txt does not exist  it will run to run a COMMAND

so every file has its own command

Comment: Can you show us what you've already tried, and the results of your efforts?

Comment: if [ -e 1.txt]; then
 echo "exist"
 
else
    echo "file does not exist"

Comment: @arpak, Formatting in comments sucks. If it's relevant to your question, [add it to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44141456/edit). Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it. Have a look at [**How To Ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidance on constructing a good question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop with `break` to leave the loop when needed:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..4} ; do
    if [[ ! -f $i.txt ]] ; then
        touch "$i".txt
        break
    fi
done
```

Note that it can break if a directory named `1.txt` exists, etc.

Comment: *grumble* re: demonstrating unquoted expansions; yes, they're safe in this context, but someone who doesn't know *why* they're safe in this context doesn't know when they can or can't copy what they see elsewhere.

Comment: i want to put different command  for different  file if dont exist

Comment: @arpak But your question doesn't mention that.

Comment: @arpak, edits that materially change the meaning of a question are only welcome here before they have answers -- if someone answered the question you asked, and you discover you then have a different question, you should ask that different question separately; after-the-fact edits that alter rather than clarify make what you have a "chameleon question"

Comment: See also [this Meta.SE question about Chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Comment: sorry i didnt know it, so what can i do now, do i need to delete question and to create new . what can i do to correct this

Comment: @arpak, deleting a question that has valid/correct answers is also unfair to those who have spent time on answers. If you feel that a correct answer was provided to the question you asked, then click the green checkmark and move on. Only delete your question if you determine that it's meaningless, unrepeatable, or off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
files=( "1.txt" "2.txt" "3.txt" "4.txt" )
comms=( "echo 10" "echo 20" "date" "touch me" )

for ((i=0; i<${#files[@]}; i++)); do
    [[ ! -f ${files[$i]} ]] && ${comms[$i]} && break
done
```

`$files` contains a space separated array of files and `$comms` contains a space separated array of corresponding commands.